# Why the event onchange is not working with class attribute?

Tags: class, cakephp, onchange

I'm having a problem with cakephp, in fact, I'm trying to use the event "onChange" in a select box, but I don't really know why it is not working when I try to set a specific class to my input.

Here is my code :

```
<form>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input(' ', array('class' => 'styledselect_pages', 'options' => array(10, 20, 40), 'empty' => 'Afficher par', 'onchange' => 'alert();'));
?>
</form>
```

​This code is not working, but if I only remove the 'class' => 'styledselect_pages' and set nothing, everything works fine !

Do I miss something ?

Edit: My styledselect_pages in my css is :

```
background: url(../img/table/select_number_rows.gif) left no-repeat;
border: none;
border-left: none;
color: #393939;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 16px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 4px 0 0 6px;
text-align: left;
width: 130px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, there is nothing wrong with this code, so I suspect that another JavaScript is active on the page that is *'capturing'* the event.

To check if this is the case, try to not *remove* the 'class' option, but (temporarily) use a different name, and check if it solves the problem,

For example:

`'class' => 'styledselect_pages-DISABLED'`

If this solves the problem and you're using some library to **'skin'** (**'style'**) the select, chances are that the whole 'select' is hidden on the page and the 'visible' drop down is not an actual drop down, but other HTML elements imitating a drop down.

Those elements may not trigger the 'on change' of the original select, therefore your function will not be called.

Comment: Wow ! Yes, it's working when I rename my class, the problem seems to come from 'jquery.selectbox-0.5_style_2', and I'm not the only one to have this problem, I will try to found How I can keep the style of the  select, but with my onChange ! Thx anyway !

Comment: Glad I could help. Skinning/styling selects is really trial and error, especially when trying to handle events as well

Answer (score 0):

try this:
function js

```
function    yourfunction(){
       alert("test");
    }
```

your code:

```
<form>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input(' ', array('class' => 'styledselect_pages', 'options' => array(10, 20, 40), 'empty' => 'Afficher par', 'onchange' => "yourfunction();"));
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Same problem, if I remove the 'class' => 'styledselect_pages' it is working (I got the box with 'test' inside), otherwise it is not :(

Comment: return some error? print the generated html of your select  @4m0ni4c